# which ip address to assign to "private" interfaces?

Tags: linux, networking, ip-address, subnet

I have an equipment powered by a cortexA CPU on which I run linux:

[image]

It has 5 network interfaces. One is actually an ethernet interface (`eth0`). The others are `tun` interfaces with which it communicates to internal peripherals via SPI channel.

According to my networking knowledge, each of the interfaces must belong to a different subnet.

The `tun` interfaces and the peripherals connected to them must be configured with well known static addresses (for application constraints). 
 For `eth0` is the user who chooses whether configured static or dynamic (either via dhcp server or via link-local address) at installation time.

The problem is that it is not possible to know a priori the subnet where `eth0` will be configured. So I don't know which subnets to assign to the `tun` interfaces.

I tried using loopback address class 127.0.0.0, changing the netmask of the `lo` interface from /8 to /16 (going out of standard). But it is not possible at the moment to run `tun` interfaces with addresses like 127.1.0.0/24.

which addresses and netmasks can I feel safer to assign to `tun` interfaces to minimize the risk of conflict with `eth0`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do it in two ways:

- using namespace (thanks to xenoid). In this way I can isolate two "network domains", for which the problem of the conflict of subnets no longer arises.
- I was able to use addresses in class 127.1.0.0/24 without having to modify the kernel.
  It is only needed to enable routing on localnet:
  `sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.<interface>.route_localnet=1`
  then, if you don't want to change netmask to the `lo` interface you can use some `iptables` rules/chains.

Answer (score 1):

IPv4 defines three blocks for private addresses:

- `192.168.*.*` (a.k.a. `192.168.0.0/16`): typically used for "small" networks (your home network, typically, so the address of your Ethernet port is likely in that range)
- `10.*.*.*` (a.k.a. `10.0.0.0/8`), typically used in enterprise intranets.
- `172.{16..31}.*.*` (a.k.a. `172.16.0.0/12`): these addresses are often used for virtual machines or Docker networks, possibly because they are less likely to clash with a "real" network using the two other blocks. This would also be your default choice for that reason.

Otherwise since you are on Linux you can investigate using [network namespaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_namespaces#Network_(net)) to isolate the addresses of the tunnel interfaces from the rest of the system. This is supported by all modern versions of the Linux kernel (this is a foundation of the Docker containers, for instance).

Comment: This is a good article on the subject: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network and also the original RFC1918: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1918

Comment: @xenoid if I choose 172.16.0.0/12 subnets there is always the risk (and bad luck) that a user wants to put the equipment in subnets that conflict with it.
Since it is foreseen that these equipments will be produced to tens of thousands for many years, my boss is afraid that such conflict can be quite frequent.

Comment: These subnets aren't a bullet-proof solution (do you want to pay for  range of addresses?) but are the less likely to conflict with something else. Otherwise since you are on Linux you can use [network namespaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_namespaces#Network_(net)) to isolate the addresses of the tunnel interfaces from the rest of the system.

Comment: @xenoid At the moment we are trying to use subnets such as 127.1.0.0/24 (changing the `lo` interface to 127.0.0.1/16). This requires us to patch the kernel (function `ipv4_is_loopback()` in `include/linux/in.h`).
The namespace solution you proposed seems more "clean" to me. I need to read more about this feature.

Answer (score 0):

There are very few addresses that you don't need to pay for *and* that won't conflict with anything.

- The 169.254.0.0/16 "link-local" address range is unlikely to be in use by any actual LAN.
- Use a small chunk of the 240.0.0.0/4 ("Class E") reserved range. While there's some small effort to un-reserve it, it's not very likely to succeed, and it's unlikely to be in use on any LAN either. (Except perhaps huge networks such as AWS.)
- Use one of the "documentation" ranges (TEST-NET-x). Probably bad advice, but not the worst.
- Buy a range of *public* addresses and hold onto it forever. "Public" means you *can* use them on the Internet, doesn't mean you have to.
- Use IPv6, with link-local addresses (the fe80:: range) which never conflict because they always require an interface to be specified.
- Use IPv6, with a randomly generated ULA address range (40 bits of randomness should be enough).